# How to change WordPress theme file path to a remote server?

Tags: wp-config, settings-api

I need to host a website on one server but have either the active theme or the entire /wp-content directory on a separate server and I can seems to get it to work.  I tried adding the following to wp-config.php

`define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://domain.tld/path/wp-content');
 define('WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://domain.tld/path/wp-content/plugins');`

The above only seems to work only if the path is to a location on the same server but I need to host these files on a remote server.  The theme alone would do.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'll be very surprised if there is a way to do this as wordpress uses both file paths and url paths to do things with themes and plugins ... and short of mapping another servers drive as a network drive to your local server I can't think of a way to get around that.

Comment: Also, to build on top of what was said above, would need to pass variables from WP core to the theme and plugins, and I can't imagine how to do that without creating a whole new api